# CSS animation not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a 3D cubical image slider. This is working fine on chrome and firefox but not on IE. This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/26/).

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".cubeSpinner").css("transform","rotateY("+(index * -90)+"deg)");
    index++;
},1500);
```

Can someone tell me how can i fix for IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these 2 pages - [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp) and [Enjoy CSS](http://enjoycss.com/5qO/code/#transform)

It will get you this -

```
.enjoy-css {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
border: none;
font: normal 16px/1 "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: black;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
```

the important part is this bit -

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
transform: rotateX(30deg);
```

I don't use IE but this *should* work. (I hope)

What you would have to do is have your jQuery change *both* the css bits.

Also, make sure your using IE10 or above. That  will fix **TONS** of HTML bugs.

Hopefully this fixes your problem!

**EDIT:** This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jabbathehutt1234/oax0vyyc/) I made. Maybe test it IE.